# What is the different between Angular Library VS Angular Custom Element (Web Components)

Tags: angular

I have a requirement to build reusable components across multiple projects. So I have surfaced on the web then I found out that we can leverage features of [Angular library](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) and [Angular custom elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements). As I understood those features acts as same. I might be wrong so can someone please explain the main differences and pros and cons of those two features as well as what would be the optimal approach to address my requirement.

Comment: are all your projects angular-based?

Comment: @k_r_i_d yes all projects are Angular 2.x

Answer (score 2):

Use an angular library. Anything you could possibly need to share between the apps you can do with a library. Services, components, interfaces, classes. Custom elements an alternate way to bootstrap a component to a page that is geared towards re-usability because it requires less setup. The two aren't comparable.